# identify series of cells in a row with similar format and extract it out

Tags: excel, vba, sequence

I am new to VBA and stuck at a specific problem. 
I have a messed up table from which i need to extract sequence of cells (highlighted in red in the image). It appears in a random pattern in the table, however always in the same sequence and format( date > Number>Number>Number>Character). I need to extract all these sequences out and collate them at the end of the table as shown in the image2. Will appreciate help on getting the code as i am new to vba and not able to do the same. the logic that I am thinking can help solve this issues
1) Loop through rows
2) match the format
3) extract values if matched
any other logic apart from checking on contiguous format can also be looked at. this is what i could come up with

New to VBA. Arrived at code logic as mentioned

As shown in image

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your logic is correct, you must iterate between rows and columns that match the condition, look for value  as date and next column on the same row must contain a numeric value, i hope this sample of code helps you

`Sub example()
Dim clm, rw, clm2, rw2, i As Long
rw2=1
'1. loop trough used range rows and columns
 For clm = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
   For rw = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
      'validate if current cell value is date
       If IsDate(Cells(rw, clm)) = True Then
       'validate if current cell value is numeric
          If IsNumeric(Cells(rw, clm + 1)) = True Then
           'add another sheet to store the values
           ' five subsequent columns same cell cells
            clm2 =1

            For i = 0 To 5
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AnotherSheet").Cells(rw2, clm2).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, clm + i)
            Next i
            rw2=rw2+1 
          End If
        End If
   Next rw
  Next clm
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

My code assumes that the `Date, Number, Number, Number, Text` cells will always be on the same row as each other (though they may be present anywhere within that row).

This code expects you to have already have a blank output sheet ready. I've added more comments to explain what's happening in the loop.

Change the value of `OUTPUT_SHEET_NAME` as necessary.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CollateValues()

    Const OUTPUT_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2" ' Change this as needed.

    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(OUTPUT_SHEET_NAME)

    ' Write hardcoded list of headers to output sheet
    outputSheet.Range("A1").Resize(1, 5) = Array("Date", "Outstanding", "Overdue", "NPI", "Status")

    Dim outputRowIndex As Long
    outputRowIndex = 1 ' Skip headers

    Dim inputSheet As Worksheet ' Used to loop over worksheets

    For Each inputSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If inputSheet.Name <> OUTPUT_SHEET_NAME Then
            With inputSheet

                Dim numericCellsFound As Range
                On Error Resume Next
                Set numericCellsFound = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) ' Suppress error if no cells were found
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not (numericCellsFound Is Nothing) Then ' Check if any cells were found on previous lines
                    Dim cell As Range
                    Dim numericCell As Range

                    ' Dates are basically numbers, so loop through all numeric cells.
                    For Each numericCell In numericCellsFound
                        If IsDate(numericCell) Then ' Check if the cell we're currently looping through is a date
                            If Application.Count(numericCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 3)) = 3 Then ' Check if the next three cells to the right of the date are all numbers. We use the worksheet function COUNT, which you may be familiar with.
                                If Application.IsText(numericCell.Offset(0, 4)) Then ' Check if the fourth cell to the right of the date is text/characters. The worksheet function ISTEXT is used.
                                    outputRowIndex = outputRowIndex + 1 ' We want to write to the next line, so increment this variable by 1.
                                    numericCell.Resize(1, 5).Copy outputSheet.Cells(outputRowIndex, "A") ' Copy-paste the 5 cells (Date, Number, Number, Number, Text), which have passed all the checks on the previous lines, to the next row on the output worksheet.
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next numericCell

                    Set numericCellsFound = Nothing ' Reset this, otherwise the current iteration's results can be affected by a previous iteration.
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next inputSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a Lot! but could you please help me explaing the numericcell loop; should i need to edit it to my need. Add more sequence or such.

Comment: also, my sub routines runs through various sheets some has this issue while others are not related. I would only want to add another sheet if this issue is found. Can you please help me with that

Comment: @HarshVardhan, I've added more comments to explain what the code does. See if it helps.